# Pivoting rows into columns Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am currently working on a table where the format of the table is something like this (all the columns are of type VARCHAR except the INSERTDATE column which is of type DATE):

```
INSERTDATE | ID   | PROPERTYNAME  | PROPERTYVALUE
----------------------------------------------
date1      | 1000 | ItemNumber    | 20.1A14
date1      | 1000 | ItemRev       | 2
date1      | 1000 | BarCodeNumber | 3854981
date2      | 1001 | ItemNumber    | 20.1B24
date2      | 1001 | ItemRev       | 1
date2      | 1001 | BarCodeNumber | 3856539
```

What I want to do is to convert all PROPERTYNAME column values into separate columns with all of their respective PROPERTYVALUE column values into their respective columns, something like this:

```
INSERTDATE | ID   | ItemNumber | ItemRev | BarCodeNumber
-------------------------------------------------------
date1      | 1000 | 20.1A14    | 2       | 3854981
date2      | 1001 | 20.1B24    | 1       | 3856539
```

I have been trying to solve this problem for days without any result. I looked up everything on Pivot on the internet but none of the examples match my own needs. I am not much familiar with Pivot in SQL so it would really be helpful if anyone can help me figure out how to use it to solve my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the columns you want, you can use conditional aggregation:

```
select insertdate, id,
       max(case when PROPERTYNAME = 'ItemNumber' then propertyvalue end) as ItemNumber,
       max(case when PROPERTYNAME = 'ItemRev' then propertyvalue end) as ItemRev,
       max(case when PROPERTYNAME = 'BarCodeNumber' then propertyvalue end) as BarCodeNumber
from t
group by insertdate, id;
```

If you don't know all the properties up-front, then you need to construct the query dynamically as a string and use `execute immediate`.

Answer (score 0):

The use case is a right candidate for `PIVOT` and you can use it perfectly here.

*Assuming you are using `Oracle` as your database* the query will look like,

```
select insertdate,id,ItemNumber,ItemRev,BarCodeNumber
  from mytable
pivot
(
 max(propertyvalue)
 for propertyname in ('ItemNumber' as ItemNumber
                     ,'ItemRev' ItemRev
                     ,'BarCodeNumber' BarCodeNumber)
)
order by insertdate;
```

Comment: @B Basak, as you specifically asked for `PIVOT` I was interested answering even there is an answer already available. Out of curiosity , did it not work with your use case ?